# Double 34 inch curved monitor to mac book pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, hdmi, setup

I have a macbook pro M1 and i need to connect 2 34 inch monitors and 2 27 inch monitors. How do i do that? Currently if i connect the two 34 inch to a docking station with hdmi the macbook recognises only 1 and the second shows as mirror not extended.

Comment: How are you connecting these monitors now?  Are they plugged into separate  ports or daisy chained from one port?

Comment: I hava a docking station which is connected to macbookpro

Comment: So, to confirm, you have a single TB or USB-C cable going to the dock, correct?  If that is the case, then you'll only get one external monitor.  Try connecting the second monitor to one of the other ports on the MacBook Pro.  You should be able to extend your desktop to that monitor as well.

Comment: So I tried connecting one monitor to the docking station which is connected to my laptop with usbc cable and the secon monitor directly to my laptop with an hdmi cable but it’s not even recognising it, the screen just goes black

Comment: You might have a cable problem.  Try swapping the cables from one device to another.

Comment: Just tried that. Not working but if i connect the two monitors to the docking station they work but again as mirrors

Comment: Forgot to add tht you should try the port on the opposite side of the MBP, not on the same side,

Comment: Having a look at the specs for the high end 16-inch MBP seem to indicate support for only **three** external monitors. https://support.apple.com/kb/SP858?locale=en_US You don't say *which* M1 MBP you have, that would be helpful as the 13-inch version only supports *one* (up to 6K) external display. Also the make/model of the displays would be helpful as well.